# Are all Ant routing algorithms the same?

Tags: routing

I am not really sure if this question is related to the Network SE or Artificial Intelligence SE. So, I asked it in both sites.

Are all **Ant routing algorithms** the same? And if No, what is the **common properties** of all of them? In other words, how we can **detect** a routing algorithm is an Ant routing algorithm?

Comment: This is really interesting but feels somewhat off-topic for us here at NE, where we're much more focussed on practical solutions to infrastructure and business networking.  I'd say that ant routing and similar heuristic search is characterised by being good at finding near-optimal routes to very large search spaces.  Routing algorithms in most practical networking are much more interested in convergence time and avoiding even temporary bad solutions.  Even ants think ants are expendable, while most organisations get cross if their packets don't arrive and the phone calls cut out.